Minimum Conditions for $\limsup_{n \to +\infty} Y_n < +\infty$ a.s. for a Supermartingale
Let $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a real-valued supermartingale.
Doob's Martingale Convergence Theorem asserts that if $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{E}[Y_n^-] < +\infty$, then $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges a.s. to an integrable random variable. In particular, this implies $\limsup_{n \to +\infty} Y_n < +\infty$ a.s.
However, this condition is too strong, as it implies that $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges a.s. Intuitively, a supermartingale tends to decrease, so I am interested in having weaker conditions, possibly related to moments or conditional moments of $Y_n$, under which $\limsup_{n \to +\infty} Y_n < +\infty$ a.s., without necessarily implying that $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges a.s.
Bounded increments supermartingales (i.e., there exists a constant $C$ such that $|Y_{n+1}-Y_{n}| \leq C$ a.s. for every $n$) also behave nicely, as we have : if $\mathbb{E}[\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (Y_n - Y_{n-1})^-] < +\infty$, then $\mathbb{P}(\liminf_{n \to +\infty} Y_n = -\infty \text{ or } \lim_{n \to +\infty} Y_n \text{ exists and is finite}) = 1$. Given this, I am interested in other cases.
In particular, I would like to know whether the condition "there exists a constant $C$ such that $\mathbb{E}(|Y_{n+1}-Y_{n}|^{2}\mid\mathcal{F}_{n}) < C$ a.s. for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$" is sufficient to guarantee $\limsup_{n \to +\infty} Y_n < +\infty$ a.s. But other related conditions are welcome.
Also, due to recurrence, the simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies $\limsup_{n \to +\infty} Y_n = +\infty$ a.s. However, this is a martingale, so a counter-example of a supermartingale that is not a martingale is preferred.

I have found a counter-example that answer one part of my question.
Consider $Y_{n} := B_{n} - \sqrt{n}$ where $B$ is the standard Brownian motion. $(Y_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a supermartingale and is not a martingale :
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y_{n+1}-Y_{n} \mid \mathcal{F}_{n}) = \mathbb{E}(B_{n+1}-B_{n}-\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\mid\mathcal{F}_{n}) = -\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n} < 0
$$
Also, let $\alpha > 0$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(|Y_{n+1}-Y_{n}|^{\alpha}\mid\mathcal{F}_{n})
& \leq \mathbb{E}((|B_{n+1}-B_{n}| + 1)^{\alpha} \mid \mathcal{F}_{n}) \\
& = \mathbb{E}[(|\mathcal{N}(0, 1)| + 1)^{\alpha}] \\
& = C_{\alpha} < +\infty
\end{aligned}
$$
By the law of the iterated logarithm for Brownian motion, $\limsup_{n\to+\infty} \frac{B_{n}}{\sqrt{2n \log\log n}} = 1$ a.s. So $\limsup_{n\to+\infty} Y_{n} = +\infty$ a.s.
